# Get days using two dates in js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having this trouble where I can only get the days between specified 2 dates. Please see the code below:

```js
var getDaysArray = function(start, end) {
  for (var arr = [], dt = start; dt <= end; dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1)) {
    arr.push(new Date(dt));
  }
  return arr;
};

var daylist = getDaysArray(new Date('08/13/2018'), new Date('08/17/2018'));
daylist.map((v) => v.toISOString().slice(0, 10)).join("");
console.log(daylist);
```

The output of the code above is:

[image]

Expected output (due to start and end dates `08/13/2018` and `08/17/2018`):

```
0: Date 2018-08-13T16:00:00.000Z
1: Date 2018-08-14T16:00:00.000Z
2: Date 2018-08-15T16:00:00.000Z
3: Date 2018-08-16T16:00:00.000Z
4: Date 2018-08-17T16:00:00.000Z
```

Note: The code above was from one of the SO answers found somewhere.

Comment: What is your expectation. Its not very clear from your question as to what output is desired

Comment: I think (and OP can correct this), they expect the first output date to be 2018-08-13 and not 2018-08-12. As explained below, OP does not actually have a problem at all.

Comment: How come it's not the same time all around the planet... It would be so simple...

Comment: Extra advice, the `Date` constructor when used with a string argument can have unexpected results in various browsers. The **only** officially supported format is ISO 8601, eg `2018-08-13` or `2018-08-13T15:00:00Z`. Be mindful that when used without a time section (ie date-only), it is treated as UTC.

Comment: @Phil Noted and thanks Phil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) represents the date in UTC format. You are probably in positive timezone offset, that's why the UTC representation of your date objects are a day off. You can use [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) instead to represent your dates in your timezone.

Another issue is that [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) retuns a new array, which you forgot to assign to `daylist` Without that assignment, no changes in `daylist` will be made.

Below snippet works as per your requirements.

```js
var getDaysArray = function(start, end) {
  for (var arr = [], dt = start; dt <= end; dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1)) {
    arr.push(new Date(dt));
  }
  return arr;
};

var daylist = getDaysArray(new Date('08/13/2018'), new Date('08/17/2018'));
daylist = daylist.map((v) => v.toLocaleString());
console.log(daylist);
```

Comment: May I also ask to format it using Day Month? e.g `14 Aug`

Comment: @Jonjie -- you may try to use `toDateString` instead of `toLocaleString`.

Comment: If I use `toDateString`, I cannot pass the format I want.

Comment: @Jonjie -- For tasks related to formatting datetime, please consider using a library such as MomentJS. That makes such work flawlessly easier.